# How to write .bat file to automatically login to pop-up wifi authentication window on Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, command

I would like to write a `.bat` file for my MacBook Air, which upon selection of a certain wifi (called CRLS) will automatically fill in the pop-up wifi login window for me.

I need my `.bat` file to:

1. Automatically try to connect to CRLS
2. When the window pops up, fill in my username and password
3. Click the Login button
4. Close the window once successful

I know I can do something similar in a `.bat` file which automatically connects to a wifi and types in the wifi password using `netsh wlan`:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid="WIFINAME"
netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=1234567890
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

However this is different since it is a pop-up login window, not a normal network key system.

Comment: Is this Windows or Mac OS X? Macs don't use "batch files"; the language of the terminal "shell" is different.

Comment: "StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck."

Comment: Mac OS X -- I guess I'm asking about the OS X equivalent then, I'm not super familiar with shell scripts, so I don't know the lingo.

Comment: If you're going to need to interact with log-in windows, that sounds more like  a job for AppleScript (or other OSA languages).

Comment: What’s the point? Connect to it once and you’ll not have to type in the details again anyway. Scripts are generally for repetitive tasks - this isn’t.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It makes me type in login details every time, I wouldn't be trying to do this otherwise.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin (I forgot to notify you in previous response)